# Why does Add-Content translates the comma separator from .TotalSeconds into a dot separator?

Tags: excel, powershell

When I use this:

```
$timer = (Get-Date)
$duration = (New-TimeSpan -Start $timer -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
$time = [math]::Round($duration,2)
Add-Content $file $time
```

I get:

[image: This is what I want]

When I use this:

```
$timer = (Get-Date)
$duration = (New-TimeSpan -Start $timer -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
$time = [math]::Round($duration,2)
Add-Content $file "some text;$time;some text"
```

I get:

[image: This is not what I want]

How do I still get a comma separator when my $time variable is between other values?

I tried to put the variable between double qoutes:

```
$timer = (Get-Date)
$duration = (New-TimeSpan -Start $timer -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
$time = [math]::Round($duration,2)
Add-Content $file "some text;""$time"";some text"
```

Anyone ideas?

Comment: Are you asking from [tag:powershell] perspective to output that double using `,` instead of `.` or are you asking from Excel perspective? because PowerShell might output the double using `,` as a separator depending on your current culture but then Excel might decide to display at its will and that would be outside the scope of PowerShell.

Comment: This is an excel issue.  Excel tries to guess the data type and often guesses wrong.  It is actually an issue with the JET and ACE drivers that are used in the backend of excel.  The best way of solving is instead of double clicking on the csv file to open, use the import data feature in excel which allow you to specify the type of each column.

Comment: But is there any way to manipulate the PowerShell output in a way that Excel will read it as a comma instead of a dot?